# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Trying to configure role/user management via ASP.NET Configuration Tool

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, user-management, security-roles

First, my development environment: Win7 laptop with Visual Studio Professional 2010.  IIS is **NOT** installed.

I'm trying to turn on and set up some roles for user management via the ASP.NET Configuration Tool, as demonstrated in the MVCMusicStore tutorial.  When I click on the 'Security' tab, I get the following error:

"There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Could not load type **'HandiGamer.MvcApplication'.**"

When I click on the 'button below', it tells me I'm using AspNetSqlProvider as my provider.  When I try to test it, it tells me:

"Could not establish a connection to the database.
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider."

Here's the thing:

1. The MVCMusicStore demo's role/user management works when I run it through the debugger.  I can add myself as a customer, and add/remove items from my cart.  *Despite* this, when I attempt to use the Configuration Tool with it, I get the same errors.
2. I actually have run aspnet_regsql on my copy of SQL Server 2008 Express.  It created the necessary tables for user management.  Still didn't fix my problem.

I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious, as the tutorial essentially said "Click two buttons and you're all set."  It literally said nothing about setting up the db for this.

I'm just stumped at this point.  Role/user management works (the MVCMusicStore proves that it does), but the configuration tool won't let me turn it on, set it up, or otherwise edit how it works.  It's becoming very frustrating.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: My web.config is as follows-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HandiGamer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|handigamer.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="HandiGamer" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="HandiGamer" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="HandiGamer" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="HandiGamer" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  Had to compile/build my solution before the config tool would 'see' the db security stuff.